# dash.js on Samsung Galaxy S4

Tags: android, mpeg-dash

I am having trouble with viewing a video on samsung galaxy s4. The video plays fine on other android devices except on Samsung Galaxy S4. The issue is the audio works fine but the the video looks distorted. The video looks fine again when I make it fullscreen. I have tried uploading a different video with the same results. I am using dash.all.js and have the below code in js file.

```
if (rml.hasDashSupport() && MediaSource.isTypeSupported('video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E,mp4a.40.2"').toString() == 'true') {
        document.writeln("<div class='dash-video-player' style='width:100%;height:100%;'><video id='videoPlayer' width='100%' height='100%' poster ='" + poster + "' controls='true'></video></div>");
        var video = document.querySelector(".dash-video-player video");
        var context = new Dash.di.DashContext();
        var player = new MediaPlayer(context);
        player.startup();
        player.attachView(video);
        player.setAutoPlay(autoPlay);
        player.attachSource(SmoothStreamingURL + "(format=mpd-time-csf)");
        return;
    }
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get any errors from the console?

You may also try the [ExoPlayer from Goolge](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer) (for Apps) or the Web-based [bitdash player](http://www.dash-player.com) (works on Galaxy S4).

Comment: I do not get any errors from the console but the video looks distorted I looked at bitdash player and it has the same problem on bitdash player. I am attaching a screenshot of how it looks on Samsung Galaxy S4. http://s27.postimg.org/695qy7pdf/CAM00013.jpg when trying to play the BigBuckBunny video. I have verified this behavior on another Samsung Galaxy S4 phone.